# How to solve this overlapping hover issue

Tags: jquery

I need to setup a hover button that can show a popup image when hovered and remove the popup image when hover out. My problem is that when I hover the button, the popup image pops and covers the button so it fires the hoverout event and remove the popup image even though the cursor is still on the button. How can I resolve this?

```
 $('.test').hover(function(){           
            imageId=$(this).next().attr('id');
            $('#div-' + imageId).show(150);
        },function (){
            $('#div-' + imageId).hide(150);
        })
```

Comment: I think you should remove the backtick formatting - easier to read.

Comment: So don't fire the `mouseleave` off the button, fire it off the popup image.

Comment: And you need to show your HTML so that somebody can provide you with a coded solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suppose the popup image doesn't cover entirely the thumbnail (or this would be trivial : simply fire the mouselave event on the popup image). Then this is a frequent problem with bubbles and menu. You have similar problems if the popup contains other mousehover sensitive areas.

You can register mouseleave events both on the thumb and the popup, and check for both if the mouse is still on target when you receive the event.

You can use this function :

```
// event is an event (usually the mouseleave)
// o is a jquery object
bubbling.eventIsOver = function(event, o) {
    if ((!o) || o==null) return false;
    var pos = o.offset();
    var ex = event.pageX;
    var ey = event.pageY;
    if (
        ex>=pos.left
        && ex<=pos.left+o.width()
        && ey>=pos.top
        && ey<=pos.top+o.height()
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

If it returns true, the mouse is still hover the popup image or the thumbnail so the popup shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

As Skarky672 said in his comment, you can go the route of setting the `mouseleave` function to be called on `mouseleave` of the image itself and since you're already setting the image id in a variable prior to this it would be quite simple.

Your code would look something like this.

```
//When hovering over the button the image pops up.
$('.test').bind('mouseenter',function(){           
            imageId=$(this).next().attr('id');
            $('#div-' + imageId).show(150);
        });
//When the mouse leaves that same image that came up, it closes the image.
$('#div-' + imageId).bind('mouseleave',function (){
            $(this).hide(150);
        });
```

Alternatively, you could simply offset the popup image from the button so the button would never be covered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with your JavaScript, but with your CSS. Consider setting up `padding` and `margin` in your CSS and make sure it wont hide the button. Also use `overflow: hidden` to your element if image is set to appear in some element like `<div>`.

Hope this helps.