# Jquery mouseleave/mouseout and z-index

Tags: jquery, z-index, mouseout, mouseleave

ttI have such navigation:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Menu title 1</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu title 1</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu title 2</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu title 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Menu title 2</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu title 1</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu title 2</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu title 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
...
```

then with jquery I set z-index for hovered  menu item higer as for submenu and fade in submenu  element. So hovered  menu item element is visible over submenu and all other menu items are under submenu.

Now i need to set mouse event for submenu  - mouseleave => hide submenu.
The problem: as  menu item is now over submenu  - if mouse stays over submenu  but hovers menu item 1,  jquery understands it as mouseleave for submenu

It is very common problem for me, I always use some kind of "cheats" but i think there must be an easy solution.

I don't provide full source code, but I don't ask you for working code, I just need some idea. Hope for help, thx.

[image]

Comment: where is your Javascript code?

Comment: Would that help ? This is my solution to this common problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024666/how-to-solve-this-overlapping-hover-issue/12024705#12024705

Comment: dystroy, thx, but this is something i called "cheats" and i'm looking for some simple solution. Everybody else: js is pretty simple - mouseenter - show submenu, mouseleave - hide submenu. Everything other is about setting and unsetting classes for visualisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you can set this up using pure CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nr8xZ/

The trick is to apply `:hover` styles to the submenus that display them only when a list item is hovered over. Since the submenu is also part of the parent list item, it stays displayed as long as the mouse is over the submenu. And you can still add additional jQuery/JavaScript interactivity to the links and/or list items, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use pureCSS menus, which is more effective and JS free. you can use this editor to generate your pureCSS menu online.

http://purecssmenu.com/

Also this is the guide to explain the basics behind the pure CSS menus.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/menus/demo.html

If you need the solution with JQuery and CSS with effects, this tutorial would help you.

http://www.instantshift.com/2010/07/16/create-simple-dropdown-menu-using-jquery/

Hope this helps.

Comment: please check the amended answer for the tutorial link. I have used this tutorial to develop my websites during the initial stages and now i'm using pureCSS menus so often. hope this solves your problems.